# Winforms: Restoring form position from a computer with two/more screens to a computer with one screen

Tags: c#, winforms, position

I am developing a small app in **Winforms** using **C#**. The user can create mutiple instances of the app and position them on the screen. When the app is closed, the app will remember the position for each window that was open(stored in an XML file). On the app restart, it will look at the XML file and try to re-open them.
The problem is if a user positions a window in a two screen-computer (in the second monitor) and then run the app in another computer with 1 screen the Window will not be in the screen since the coordinates do not exist. It's worth mentionning that in a one-scrren computer, i can see the window is there(it is in the taskbar).  Is there a way to calculate the new position for the window? or?

Comment: Look at the `Screen` class.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you so much, The screen clas did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the number of screen by using the [Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in System.Windows.Forms. [AllScreens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) contains the list of all screens currently on the system. If your saved position is no longer valid for this layout you should probably reset the position to a default one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's exactly what I did :)

Answer (score 0):

As @SLaks mentioned in the comments the scrren class helped me achieve what I needed. By simply getting the bounds of the screen and and comparing to the stored coordinates I manged to solve the problem:

```
mainWindow.Location = (Screen.AllScreens.Length == 1 && savedWindow.Location.X > Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Width) ? new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0) : savedWindow.Location;
```